# R - Polygon tearing when trying to merge .csv to .shp files

Tags: r, merge, polygon, shapefile

I'm trying to associate data per country ('prop') in a .csv file to each corresponding polygon in a .shp file, however, the polygons do not map correctly after I try the `merge` function.

First I create the polygons using `fortify`, splitting by the 3-letter country code in the .shp file...

```
gpclibPermit()
worldmapDf<- fortify(worldmap, region="ISO_3_CODE")
```

Then I attempt to associate 'prop' data from the .csv file, matching by the 3-letter country code column ('code' in this case).

```
forestareamap <- merge(worldmapDf, forestarea, by.x="id", by.y="code")
```

Then I try to plot it...

```
ggplot(forestareamap)+aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=prop)+geom_polygon()
```

And this happens...

[image]

Obviously the polygons are not drawing in the correct order, but I'm not sure how to order them correctly.

Plotting the data directly after the fortify generates the correct polygons, so something is going amiss with the merge function. Being a complete rookie, I have no idea...

Comment: try merge(..., sort=FALSE) ?

Comment: CAn you give us access to `worldmap`? Almost certainly you haven't used `fortify` quite right. Polygons are being drawn correctly, but `ggplot2` doesn't know how to group them/where one starts and another finishes.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with my data.  Merge messes with the ordering, causing this problem.  Try:

```
forestareamap <- forestareamap[order(forestareamap$order),] 
ggplot(forestareamap)+aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=prop)+geom_polygon()
```

This should put everything back in the correct order.